# More options for managing node display

Tags: nodes, entities

I am trying to clean up the node pages and am finding very few options under the Manage Display tab. Do I have to dig in to the code and css to get some more control or is there a module that allows for greater customization in this area?

I am thinking about options similar to what Views allows.

- Adding relationships to pull in related content. e.x. author name from profile instead of using username.
- A specific example: One content type has a photo and alot of text, and I want the text to wrap around the photo.

Comment: It's basically impossible to answer this as we can't read your mind...what options are you _expecting_ to be there? What do you need to change?

Comment: That again said, requirements are very very varid to provide any specific details. response to two queries:
1. Views is not cleaning up. You can use it to pull in related contents and then place them either in template/panels.
2. The second one can be achieved through mere css. 

In general please read my response to gain some idea and chose which way you would like to go. my suggestion if you are not comfortable with html/css go for panels. This will help you fix layouts and make views blocks placement easy for you through drag-drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, as Clive said it is difficult to give answer to a question that broad in scope. But in general there are two broad directions:

1. Use Modules like Panels and Display Suite - These allows customizations in node pages by allowing you to chnage layout, add different contents etc.
2. Follow custom theaming path. this involves writing modifying the preprocess function and modifying the node.tpl.php

Any more specific info will require you to give out more details in terms of what you want exact in terms of layout and "clean up"